# How to gunzip without delete?

Tags: linux, centos

How to unzip `.gz` all archives without delete in specified folder?

I tried: `gunzip *.gz /folder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done with some `bash` scripting using `gzip` `--stdout` option and compute the uncompressed name with bash substitution:

```bash
for i in *.gz
do
   echo unzipping $i to /folder/${i/.gz}
   gunzip --stdout "$i" > "/folder/${i/.gz}"
done
```

the current implementation fails with filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use -k option specified in man.

```
-k --keep
        Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.
```

For example if you use the command

```
gunzip -k my_file.gz
```

my_file.gz will not be deleted after compression or decompression.

Comment: The OP also wants to move uncompressed files into another directory

Comment: Ok so he can use tar instead of gzip or gunzip.

Comment: by using tar z file.gz -C /dest/path

Comment: `gzip: invalid option -- 'k'
Try `gzip --help' for more information.
`

Comment: Sorry tar xzvf myfile.gz -X /tmp

Comment: And myfile.gz is not deleted

Comment: `tar: option requires an argument -- 'X'
`

Comment: use -C not -X to specify dest folder

Comment: The -k option requires gzip 1.6 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Use gzip to unzip to stdout and pipe that to your required file (as -k option doesn't work for me either

```
gzip -dc somefile.gz > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good substitute for gzip version < 1.6 ("-k" option was introduced in version 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

```
find /source/dir/ -type f -name '*.gz' \
  -exec bash -c 'gunzip -c "$0" > "/folder/${0%.gz}"' {} \;
```

This command finds all `*.gz` files in `/source/dir/` directory and executes a bash command for each file. The bash command uncompresses the file (`$0`) to the standard output and redirects the result to `"/folder/${0%.gz}"`. The latter is the `"/folder/"` string concatenated with the filename without `.gz` extension. The `${0%.gz}` expression removes shortest match for `.gz` from the back of the string (the path).

And the `{}` sequence is replaced with path of the next gzipped file. It is passed to the bash command as the first argument (`$0`).

Replace `/source/dir/` with dot (`.`), if the source directory is the current directory.